# Strapi typescript: how to properly use strapi.entityService.findOne

Tags: typescript, strapi

I always getting errors:

```
Type '...' does not satisfy the constraint 'never'
```

When calling:

`strapi.entityService.findOne("entity", "id", {});`

How to properly use this function on strapi?

Answer (score 0):

The `"entity"` argument needs to be a UID like `api::page.page` and the `"id"` argument needs to be a number ID for an existing entity.

```
await strapi.entityService.findOne('api::page.page', 3, {});
```